# login and registration modal animation is not working

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to enable a login/register modal from an example I found on TS and using it in React.

The login looks like :

[image]

The objectif is :

- When you press the `Sign up`, it trigger a transition where the orange part become a signup form and the left side became an orange layout to allow you to sigin.

For now, I was able to make the login layout but the press on signup is not triggering anything.

for now, the code complain about `this.container.current` do not have `.current`.

I add here the code

```
import React from "react";
import { Modal } from "react-bootstrap";
import './Login.css';
import Auth from '../../data/network/Auth';
import Constant from '../../config/Constant';

class LoginRegisterModal extends React.Component {  

    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          show: false, 
          rightActive: false,
          email: '',
          password: '',
          userNiceName: '',
          loggedIn: false,
          loading: false,
          error: '',
        };
    }

    open = () => {
        this.setState({show: true});
    }
    
    close = () => {
        this.setState({show: false});
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
    /*  this.signup.current.addEventListener('click', () => {
        console.log("SIGNUPSIGNUPSIGNUPSIGNUPSIGNUPSIGNUPSIGNUPSIGNUP")
        this.container.current.classList.add('right-panel-active');
      });  

     this.signin.current.addEventListener('click', () => {
        console.log("SIGNINSIGNINSIGNINSIGNINSIGNINSIGNINSIGNINSIGNINSIGNINSIGNIN")
        this.container.current.classList.remove('right-panel-active');
      });  */
    }

    onSignupClick = () => {
      console.log("SIGNUPSIGNUPSIGNUPSIGNUPSIGNUPSIGNUPSIGNUPSIGNUP")
      this.setState({rightActive: false})
      this.container.classList.add('right-panel-active')
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        const { show } = this.props;
        if (prevProps.show !== show) {
          if (show) {
            this.open(); // open if parent says to
          } else {
            this.close(); // close if parent says to
          }
        }
    }

    requestSignIn = async (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();

      this.setState({loading: true})

      try {
        const authData = await Auth.getToken(`${this.state.email}`, `${this.state.password}`);
        sessionStorage.setItem(Constant.ALL, authData)
        sessionStorage.setItem(Constant.AUTH_TOKEN, authData.token)
        sessionStorage.setItem(Constant.DISPLAY_NAME, authData.user_display_name)
        sessionStorage.setItem(Constant.EMAIL, authData.user_email)
        sessionStorage.setItem(Constant.NICENAME, authData.user_nicename)

        window.open("/", "_self") //to open new page
        this.setState({loading: false })
        this.close()
      } catch (error) {
        console.warn("Connection to WP - Auth Token failed ")
        console.error(error);
      } 
    }

    handleOnChange = (event) => {
      this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value})
    }

    createAccount = () => {
      this.close()
    }

    requestForgotPassword = () => {
      this.close()
    }
      
    render() { 

      const signUpButton = this.refs.signUp; //document.getElementById('signUp');
      const signInButton = document.getElementById('signIn');
      const container = document.getElementById('container');

      signUpButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        container.classList.add("right-panel-active");
      });
      
      signInButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        container.classList.remove("right-panel-active");
      });


    const { email, password, rightActive } = this.state;
        
    const loginModal = <div class="container" id="container">
                  <div class="form-login-container sign-up-container"> 
                    <form action="#">
                      <h1 style={styleHeaderBlack}>Sign up.</h1>
                      <div class="social-container">
                      <a href="#" class="social"><i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i></a>
                      <a href="#" class="social"><i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i></a>
                      <a href="#" class="social"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
                      </div>
                      <span style={styleTxtBlack}>or use your email for registration</span>
                      <input style={formStyle} type="text" placeholder="Name" />
                      <input style={formStyle} type="email" placeholder="Email" />
                      <input style={formStyle} type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                      <button style={whiteBtnStyle} onClick={this.createAccount}>Sign Up</button>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-login-container sign-in-container">
                  <form onSubmit={this.requestSignIn}>
                    <h1 style={styleHeaderBlack}>Sign in.</h1>
                    <div class="social-container">
                        <a href="#" class="social"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
                        <a href="#" class="social"><i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i></a>
                        <a href="#" class="social"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
                    </div>
                    <span style={styleTxtBlack}>or use your account</span>
                      <input style={formStyle} 
                        type="text" 
                        placeholder="Email" 
                        name="email"
                        value={ email }
                        onChange={ this.handleOnChange } />
                    <input style={formStyle} 
                        type="password" 
                        placeholder="Password"
                        name="password"
                        value={ password }
                        onChange={ this.handleOnChange }/>
                    <a style={styleTxtBlack} href="#" onClick={this.requestForgotPassword} >Forgot your password?</a>
                    <button style={whiteBtnStyle} type="submit" >Sign In</button>
                  </form>
                  </div>
                  <div class="overlay-container">
                    <div class="overlay">
                      <div class="overlay-panel overlay-left">
                          <h1 style={styleHeaderWhite}>Sign in.</h1>
                          <p style={styleTxtWhite}>
                            Nice to see you again.Login and continue the journey.
                          </p>
                          <button style={whiteBtnStyle} class="ghost" id="signIn">Sign In</button>
                      </div>
                      <div class="overlay-panel overlay-right">
                          <h1 style={styleHeaderWhite}>Hey, new friend!</h1>
                          <p style={styleTxtWhite}>New to the Village? Sign up and start your journey</p>
                          <button style={whiteBtnStyle} class="ghost" id="signUp">Sign Up</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>;

      return (       
        <Modal className="modal" show={this.state.show}  size="lg" > 
            {loginModal}
        </Modal>
        );  
    }  
}  
  
export default LoginRegisterModal;
```

and the css is :

```
h1 {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0;
}

p {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    margin: 20px 0 30px;
}

span {
    font-size: 12px;
}

a {
    color: #333;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 15px 0;
}

button {
    border-radius: 200px;
    border: #ff7255;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #ff7255;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 18px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14);
    text-align: center;
}

button:active {
    transform: scale(0.95);
}

button:focus {
    outline: none;
}

button.ghost {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-color: #ffffff;
}

form {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0 50px;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

input {
    background-color: #eee;
    border: none;
    padding: 12px 15px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.social-container {
    margin: 20px 0;
}

.social-container a {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 5px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}

.modalLogin {
    background-color: #ff4b2b;
    margin-top: "15%";
    margin-left: "30%";
    padding: 0;
    width:770px;
    height:480px;
    border-radius:21.5px;
}

.modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  }

.containerLogin {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 768px;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 480px;
}

.form-login-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.sign-in-container {
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    z-index: 2;
}

.sign-up-container {
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.container.right-panel-active .sign-in-container {
    transform: translateX(100%);
}

.container.right-panel-active .sign-up-container {
    transform: translateX(100%);
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 5;
    animation: show 0.6s;
}

@keyframes show {
    0%,
    49.99% {
        opacity: 0;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    50%,
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        z-index: 5;
    }
}

.overlay-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 100;
}

.container.right-panel-active .overlay-container {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.overlay {
    background: #ff7255;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 0 0;
    color: #ffffff;
    position: relative;
    left: -100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200%;
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.container.right-panel-active .overlay {
    transform: translateX(50%);
}

.overlay-panel {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0 40px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.overlay-left {
    transform: translateX(-20%);
}

.container.right-panel-active .overlay-left {
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.overlay-right {
    right: 0;
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.container.right-panel-active .overlay-right {
    transform: translateX(20%);
}
```

I feel that it just missing a little bridge to make it works.

Here is the link I have used to start: https://codepen.io/FlorinPop17/pen/vPKWjd

Answer (score 1):

Avoid accessing the actual DOM like that, after all React should take care of this and you'd rarely have to manually work with the DOM yourself.

For class components the correct way to create a ref to an element is (although I'm not sure if you need ref in your case at all):

```
const myRef = React.createRef();
...
<button ref={myRef} style={whiteBtnStyle} class="ghost" id="signUp">Sign Up</button>
```

Also attach events in JSX, the React way, if posible:

```
<button onClick={onSignUpClick} style={whiteBtnStyle} class="ghost" id="signUp">Sign Up</button>
```

In the component, define an instance method instead of using inline function in the JSX, to avoid recreating the function on each render (not that it's a big deal, but I think JSX is more clear that way, too):

```
onSignUpClick = () => {
   this.setState({
     rightPanelActive: true
   });
}
```

and finally, use class binding in your JSX for the container to toggle its class (**note you should use className as class is a reserved keyword in JS**):

```
<div className={`container ${this.state.rightPanelActive ? "right-panel-active" : ""`} id="container">
```

And one last thing - if you're using ids for your elements, make sure they don't repeat anywhere in your page. If you have two modal components, ids will repeat and your html will no longer be vald.